# CSS h1 first-letter or first-child issue

Tags: html, css

I can't find a solution, but I want to make the first letter of an `<h1>` be bigger than the rest.

Here is my code:

```css
.heading {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.heading h1 {
  display: table;
  width: 75%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #14304f
}

.heading h1:before,
.heading h1:after {
  content: '';
  width: 40%;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/10x1/000/000.png") repeat-x center center;
  display: table-cell;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.heading h1:before {
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}

.heading h1:after {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.heading h1:first-child {
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h1>
    HEADING
  </h1>
</div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/deelite310/pen/zRjVJx

Comment: See the [`::first-letter` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter).

Comment: Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/

Comment: Oh, I see that `::first-letter` doesn't work as expected due to `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Also, `::first-letter` only works on `block` or `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudo-elements are messing up the property you are trying to use which is `::first-letter`, not `:first-child`. Here is a reworked version using flex:

```css
.heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #14304f;
}

.heading h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading::before,
.heading::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.heading h1::first-letter {
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `span` inside `h1` and

`.heading h1 span {
  font-size: 150%;
}`

```css
.heading {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.heading h1 {
  display: table;
  width: 75%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #14304f
}

.heading h1:before,
.heading h1:after {
  content: '';
  width: 40%;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/10x1/000/000.png") repeat-x center center;
  display: table-cell;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.heading h1:before {
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}

.heading h1:after {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.heading h1:first-child {
  font-size: 125%;
}

.heading h1 span {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h1>
    <span>H</span>EADING
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, so I'll see if I can use it another time. the solution below actually works better for what I'm doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
.heading h1:first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

remove all of your previous styles first as some of it conflicts with this. use this style.